# Display the selected value in another DIV element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am asking the user to select his/her gender . Later on I want to display the selected gender in another `<div>` element as shown below. How can I do this?

```
<div id="v1">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Male or Female</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <select id="gender" name="gen">
                    <option>Male</option>
                    <option>Female</option>
                    <option>Do not wish to specify</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now I need to display the selected value in another `<div>`:

```
<div id="v2">
     <h2>I WANT TO DISPLAY THE SELECTED VALUE HERE</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#gender').change(function(){
   $('#v2 h2').text($('#gender').val())
});`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code if you are using jQuery.

```
$("#gender").change(function() {
    $("#v2 h2").html($(this).val());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gxb97/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also want to get the value of the textfield and display it in that view. I have forgotten to add the code to my post. How can i do this?

Comment: You mean after the h2 containing the gender? And where is the textfield you are saying?

Comment: After user selects the gender, the user will enter some text onto the textfield. How can i get these values and display in the <div id="v2"> section.

Comment: There is no textfield currently in your question, please update it accordingly so we can help you. And you want both to display in the h2 inside `<div id="v2">`? or in another node?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#selection").on("change", function () {
        var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        $('#v2 h2').text(text);
    });
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w9kWU/1/)

To get also the value:

```
$(function () {
    $("#selection").on("change", function () {
        var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        var value = $(this).val();
        var string = 'Text: '+text+' - Value: '+value;
        $('#v2 h2').text(string);
    });
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w9kWU/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact-location').change(function(){
        var location = $(this).val(),
        div = $('#' + location);
var txt=$('#txtfiled11').val();
        div.append(txt);
        $('.hide').hide();
             div.show();

    });
});
```

**[Another Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/vWLsU/265/)**

[**Update Fiddle DEMO with TEXTFIELD VALUE3**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/vWLsU/266/)

Use

```
 $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also want to get the value of the textfield and display it in that view. I have forgotten to add the code to my post. How can i do this?

Comment: Thanks. This helps. But i am wondering what happens if the user fills the textfield after selecting values from the dropdown. In that case, your solution will not help. Any idea how to solve this ?